# Python - explanation of pathlib.Path.mkdir mode argument

Tags: python, pathlib

Please help understand how **mode=511** is translated into the directory permission "775" in `Pathlib.Path.mkdir()`.

- [`Path.mkdir(mode=511, parents=False, exist_ok=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

> Path.mkdir(mode=511, parents=False, exist_ok=False)
> Create a new directory at this given path. If mode is given, it is combined with the process’ umask value to determine the file mode and access flags.

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path("/tmp/hoge").mkdir(mode=511)
```

```
$ ls -dal
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec 30 16:24 /tmp/hoge

$ umask
0002

$ python --version
3.8.10
```

Not sure what is the logic behind.

```
# For mode=611
d--xr----t 2 user user 4096 Dec 30 16:37 /tmp/hoge

# For mode=411
drw--wx--x 2 user user 4096 Dec 30 16:38

# For mode=311
dr--rw-r-x 2 user user 4096 Dec 30 16:39 /tmp/hoge
```

Comment: the integer 511 is converted to octal value `511 =
0o777`. Now since you have umask 0002, its overriden as 775.

Comment: @Kris, thank you. So mode=511 is decimal/10 number, hence it is octal 777...

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much I have understood :-)

Answer (score 3):

As per @Kris.

```
dec=511

print("The decimal value of", dec, "is:")
print(bin(dec), "in binary.")
print(oct(dec), "in octal.")
print(hex(dec), "in hexadecimal.")
---
The decimal value of 511 is:
0b111111111 in binary.
0o777 in octal. # <--- rwxrwxrwx
0x1ff in hexadecimal.
```

Then umask `002` is applied and becomes `775/rwxrwxrx`.

Comment: For newbies like me: it's convenient to use *octal* because `rwx` is composed of *3* characters. Each character can be represented by 0 or 1, so it becomes 3 digits binary(000~111), which is just 1 digit in octal(0~7). Note: the *umask* value is in *octal*. E.g., if the umask is 002, octal 777(rwx rwx rwx) becomes 775(rwx rwx r-x), and if the umask is 022, octal 777 becomes 755(rwx r-x r-x).